# TLS 1.2 + C# + BouncyCastle

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, tls1.2

To support TLS 1.1 and above on WinCE we are using BouncyCastle library, but when making a connection it throws error "Internal TLS error, this could be an attack".

Can someone advice on this.

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();

client.Connect(resolvedIpAddr, PORT_TLS_11);

Org.BouncyCastle.Security.SecureRandom sr = new Org.BouncyCastle.Security.SecureRandom();
TlsProtocolHandler handler = new TlsProtocolHandler(client.GetStream(), sr);

handler.Connect(new MyTlsClient());
```

Comment: If possible, first check that the TcpClient can connect (i.e. without any TLS) to rule out network problems. Then try overriding the NotifyAlertRaised and NotifyAlertReceived methods (in MyTlsClient) and log the arguments to see what the underlying problem might be (don't panic about the error message you're getting, it's just a generic message).

Comment: @PeterDettman i don't see those as available overrides

Comment: @Sinaesthetic Check you have the latest release (1.8.1). The methods are on the TlsPeer interface, which is extended by TlsClient and thus available for override if you are subclassing e.g. DefaultTlsClient.

Comment: getting error "handshake_failure"  in NotifyAlertReceived method