# TLS 1.2 + C# + BouncyCastle example

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, bouncycastle, tls1.2, windows-xp-embedded

I am trying to connect to server via TLS1.2 using .Net 2.0.

I have tried the bouncy castle tls client but getting ""Internal TLS error, this could be an attack"

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();

client.Connect(resolvedIpAddr, PORT_TLS_11);

Org.BouncyCastle.Security.SecureRandom sr = new Org.BouncyCastle.Security.SecureRandom(); 
TlsProtocolHandler handler = new TlsProtocolHandler(client.GetStream(), sr);

handler.Connect(new MyTlsClient());
```

Could some one please help us here by example or any other way.
Also if any other lib/api for TLS1.2 support in .Net 2.0

Comment: On which OS are you running that .Net 2.0 code?

Comment: windows xp embeded and POS ready 2009

Comment: Can you provide the diagnostics that are asked for in the comments [on this duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33776495/tls-1-2-c-sharp-bouncycastle)

Comment: added comment on that thread. 
 
getting error "handshake_failure" in NotifyAlertReceived method